# What's the first time-integral of price called?

Tags: finance, mathematics

In general I'm wondering about the names of time-derivatives of price.

E.g. in physics the first few time-derivatives of position are:

- f(x) = displacement
- f'(x) = velocity
- f''(x) = acceleration

And the first integral (anti-derivative) of displacement is called *absement*.

What would the equivalent financial terms be?

Comment: What your looking for is Stochastic Calculus

Answer (score 2):

Although I don't think that this is a question that fits in here, I will give you a reference.

You might want to have a look at the so called greeks, you find a first overview here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greeks_(finance)

Comment: I'm sorry but this question has nothing to do with options. It's about mathematical derivatives of price.

Comment: @Tom: Price of *what*? *Derivatives* are called that way for a reason.

Comment: Options are derivatives because their price is not a free variable but depends on the price of 1 or more other instruments. My question is about any instrument whose price is (presumed to be) a free variable e.g. equity, fx, commodities.

Comment: I'm not sure a physics approach is helpful. Maybe you could pick up a book on stochastic calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you divide a time integral by the length of the time interval, you'll get the average (in time) price:
$$
  \frac{1}{t}\int_0^T x_t\mathrm dt
$$
so *at least* on of the meanings of the integral itself is an average price time the length of the interval. In such a case, I think the normalized quantity (the integral divided by the length) is more meaningful. It is used e.g. in the exotic options whose payoff depends on the average price.